# Compare values from cx_oracle cursor with django queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset, cx-oracle

In my project I collect data from an oracle database using cx_Oracle and then I need to compare the result from the cx_Oracle cursor with data from a SQLite database for which I have models.

I have the following code which works for adding missing parameters:

```
    def GetParams(self):
    repo_params = Parameters.objects.filter(dbid=self.dbid).only('name','value')
    sql = ("select name, value from v$parameter")
    self.cur.execute(sql)
    res = self.cur.fetchall()
    repo_params = list(repo_params)
    parameters = []
    for i in res:
        if i[1] not in repo_params:
            new_param = Parameters(name=i[1],value=i[2])
            parameters.append(new_param)
    if len(parameters) > 0:
        Parameters.objects.bulk_create(parameters)
```

But what I actually want to do is to merge existing content in my SQLite database with the one from the cursor. If an existing parameter exists with a different values then I need to update its value. If it's a new parameter, then it need to be created. What is the best way to do this? Should I do a MERGE using RAW sql?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question. 
This is a simplified way to handle both inserting new parameters and updating existing ones in SQLite:

```
    from django.db import connection

    def GetParams(self):
    sql = ("select name, value from v$parameter")
    self.cur.execute(sql)
    res = self.cur.fetchall()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    for i in res:
        cursor.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE
                          INTO Parameters(dbid, name, value)
                          VALUES( %s, %s, %s)''',[self.dbid,i[0],i[1]]
                      )
    connection.commit()
```

**UPDATE:**

Even better:

```
 def GetParams(self):
    sql = ("select :dbid, name, value from v$parameter")
    named_params = {'dbid': self.dbid}
    self.cur.execute(sql, named_params)
    res = self.cur.fetchall()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.executemany('INSERT OR REPLACE\n'
                       'INTO Parameters(dbid, name, value)\n'
                       'VALUES( ?, ?, ?)', res
                       )
```